# TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mongoose, typeerror, iterable

I have the following code:

```js
    //creates matrix and converts it to JSON file
    var map = JSON.stringify(math.randomInt([10, 10],2));

    //create instance of Map
    const temp= new Map({_id: 2, map: map});
    temp.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
    
    });
```

This creates a matrix and puts it into my mongoDB in the Map collection with the following model:

```js
const mapSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    _id: Number,
    map: Array
})
  
const Map = mongoose.model('Map', mapSchema)
```

And this works fine. but I want to put the whole first snippet into a function, so I can put it in another file, import it in my index.js and there just run this function. So I put a function around it, like so:

```js
const generateMap = function() {
    var map = JSON.stringify(math.randomInt([10, 10],2));

    const temp = new Map({_id: 2, map: map});
    temp.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
    
    });
    
};
```

I export the function to my index.js file and run the function there, but I get the error:

```js
const temp= new Map({_id: 2, map: map});
             ^

TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Can naybody help me with this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In the situation where you get the error, you're inadvertently using JavaScript's standard `Map` constructor, not your own `Map` constructor. If you pass an argument to JavaScript's `Map` constructor, that argument must be iterable.

So the fix is to make sure *your constructor* is the one in scope where you use it.

I ***strongly*** recommend not naming things so that they conflict with things in the JavaScript standard library. Perhaps consider calling your constructor `XYZMap` where `XYZ` is something that identifies what it means in your schema. Then you won't have the name conflict and you'll get a more obvious error when you don't have it in scope. (The error would be `ReferenceError: XYZMap is not defined` which hopefully makes it clearer what's happening.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. I am new to JS and don't know the naming conventions.